# How to avoid multiple API calls

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to optimize an application but I'm kinda struggling to understand one logic and would like some hints, here's my problem :

I have a card that is a component (right component):

[image]

In another component I can pick articles to put in the cards (left component) :

[image]

***What my left component does***

At the moment, my left component sends the input to an API and subscribe to the response to emit the datas he received to the right component.

***What my right component does***

Right component initialize himself at the start by checking if there's already data or not to be rendered. When left component sends datas to the API, right component subscribe to the response and do an **`NgOnChanges`** in order to modify it structures.

The problem is that it's making 5 time the API calls for only 1 change in left component so my question is, how to send datas to right component and rendering them properly in the card with only 1 API call ?

**Left component :**

```
import {Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnChanges, OnInit, Output} from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';
import {QuotationMenuService} from '../../quotation-menu.service';
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
import {environment} from '../../../../../../../environments/environment';
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { orderBy } from 'lodash';

@Pipe({
  name: 'orderBy'
})
export class OrderByPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform = orderBy;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-network-template',
  templateUrl: './network-template.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./network-template.component.scss'],
})
export class NetworkTemplateComponent implements OnChanges, OnInit {

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
              private service: QuotationMenuService,
              private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
  ) { }

  get f() {
    return this.networkForm.controls;
  }

  networkForm: FormGroup;

  @Input()dataDynLevel: number;
  @Input()dataDynParts: Event;
  @Input()quotationId: Event;
  @Input() longueur: number;
  @Input() quantity: number;

  @Output() sendTotalLevelNetwork = new EventEmitter<any>();

  dataDiam1: any;
  dataDiam2: any;
  filteredWithDiam: any;
  quotArray: any;
  part_id: any;
  photos: any;
  photosPath = environment.photosPath;

  selectedDiam: any;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.createForm();
    this.initQuot();
  }




  initQuot() {
    this.service.urlQuot = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('quotId');
    this.service.checkExistQuot().subscribe(res => {
      this.quotArray = res.quotation.quotationdetail2;
      console.log(this.quotArray, 'QUOT ARRAY')
      this.networkForm.patchValue({
          quantity: this.selectedDiam.quantity,
          longueur: this.selectedDiam.longueur
        },
        {emitEvent: true});
    });
  }



  createForm() {
    this.networkForm = this.formBuilder.group(
      {
        diameter1: [''],
        diameter2: [''],
      }
    );
  }



  postQuotationDatas(id, part, typeAppel) {
    this.part_id = part.part_id;
    this.service.part_id = this.part_id;
    this.service.part_type = 'network';
    if (typeAppel === 'longueur') {
      this.service.quantity = 0;
      this.service.longueur = id;
      part.longueur = id;
    } else {
      this.service.quantity = id;
      this.service.longueur = part.longueur;
      part.quantity = id;
    }
    this.service.postQuotationDatas().subscribe( data => {
      this.sendTotalLevelNetwork.emit(data);
      console.log(data, 'POST DONE');
    });  }
}
```

**Right component**

```
import {AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, Input, OnChanges, OnInit, SimpleChanges, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';
import {QuotationMenuService} from '../quotation-menu.service';
import {ExcelService} from '../../../../accueil/services/excel.service';
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';





@Component({
  selector: 'app-right',
  templateUrl: './right.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./right.component.scss']
})
export class RightComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnChanges, OnInit {

  get f() {
    return this.cartForm.controls;
  }

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
              private service: QuotationMenuService,
              private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
              ) {

  }

  @Input()TotalLevelRight: any;

  @ViewChild('pdfTable', {static: false}) pdfTable: ElementRef;

  collapse = true;
  showMainOeuvre: boolean;
  showAleas: boolean;
  showSupportage: boolean;
  cartForm: FormGroup;
  quotArray: any;
  quotDetails: any;
  cartDetails: any;
  labels: any;
  label_name: any;
  total_by_level: any;
  array: any;
  totalPrice: any;
  totalLevelChanges: any;
  totalPerCat: any;
  output_object2 = Object.create(null);
  output_object = Object.create(null);
  currencyCode: any;
  totalTotal: any;



  ngOnInit() {


  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    this.requiredFields();
    this.service.getStructure().subscribe(res => {
      this.labels = res.parts;
      this.label_name = res.labels_levels;
      /*      console.log(this.labels);
            console.log(this.label_name);*/

    });
    this.service.postQuotationDatas().subscribe(data => {
      this.initQuot();
      console.log('INIT QUOT IN CHANGE TRIGGERED')
    });
    console.log('PASSAGE PAR NgOnChanges')
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {


  }

  initQuot() {
    this.service.checkExistQuot().subscribe(res => {
      this.service.urlQuot = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('quotId');
      console.log(res);
      this.totalTotal = res.quotation.total_total;
      this.currencyCode = res.quotation.currency_code;
      this.quotArray = res;
      this.quotDetails = res.quotation.quotationdetail;
      this.totalPrice = (res.quotation.total_fourniture + res.quotation.time_main_oeuvre + res.quotation.total_aleas + res.quotation.meter_supportage);
      this.cartDetails = res.cart;
      this.total_by_level = res.cart.total_by_level;
/*
      console.log(this.total_by_level);
*/
      if ( res.quotation.total_aleas === null) {
        this.showAleas = false;
      } else {
        this.showAleas = true;
      }
      if ( res.quotation.time_main_oeuvre === null) {
        this.showMainOeuvre = false;
      } else {
        this.showMainOeuvre = true;
      }
      if ( res.quotation.meter_supportage === null) {
        this.showSupportage = false;
      } else {
        this.showSupportage = true;
      }
      const result = Object.values(this.total_by_level).map(items => Object.values(items)
        .map(val => Number(val))
        .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0).toFixed(2));
      this.totalPerCat = result;
/*
      console.log(result);
*/
    });

  }





  requiredFields() {
    this.cartForm = this.formBuilder.group(
      {

      }
    );
  }

}
```

If anyone could lead on the way to do proper API calls I'd be really grateful for it, thank's for your help.

EDIT :

Left component html :

```
<div class="container wid">
  <form [formGroup]="networkForm">
    <div class="desc d-flex flex-row">
      <a class="flex1 bold">Photo</a>
      <div class="flex1">
        <label for="diam1" class="bold">ø Network
        <select id="diam1" (click)="filterDiam1()"  formControlName="diameter1" class="form-control ml-1 diam">
          <option value="">All</option>
          <option [value]="diam1" *ngFor="let diam1 of dataDiam1">{{diam1}}</option>
        </select>
        </label>
      </div>
      <a class="flex1 bold">Price/meter</a>
      <a class="flex1 bold">Meter</a>
      <a class="flex1 bold">Total price</a>
    </div>
  </form>
  <div>
  </div>
  <div class="products">
    <div class="border flex-shrink-0">

      <div class="d-flex flex-row " *ngFor="let products of selectedDiam | orderBy: ['part_image','part_diameter1_id']"
           [ngClass]="{
            'linesColor' : products.longueur > 0 || products.quantity > 0,
            'negative' : products.longueur < 0 || products.quantity < 0
         }">
        <img src="{{photosPath}}{{products.part_image}}" style="max-width: 170px; max-height: 100px" class=" flex1">
        <a class="ml-2 flex1" style="padding-left: 50px">{{products.diam}}</a>
          <a class=" flex1" style="padding-left: 50px">{{products.price1}}</a>
          <a class=" flex1 mb-1" style="padding-left: 50px">
            <input ngModel="{{products.longueur}}"  (ngModelChange)="postQuotationDatas($event,products,'longueur')" class="number" type="number">
          </a>
          <a style="padding-left: 50px" class="ml-5 flex1">{{products.price1}}</a>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Right component HTML :

```
<div class="container dpf wid police" >
  <form [formGroup]="cartForm">
  <div class="flex-row p10 bg-gray">
    <h1>Estimation
      <small class="white">
      </small></h1>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-col dim-card flex90 p5 overflow-auto">
    <table class="bg-white" id="excel-table">
      <tr class="flex1">
        <th class="unsetBold">Longueur totale réseau</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="flex1">
        <th class="unsetBold">Longueur totale descentes</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="flex1">
        <th class="unsetBold">Temps de pose estimé</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="flex1 medium-font dark-grey-text bg-grey bold">
        <th>MATERIEL Transair ® : </th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="flex1">
        <th>TOTAL FOURNITURE TRANSAIR</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="flex1 ml-2 smallText">
        <th class="pl-4">* Prix public basé sur le tarif EMEA 2019, valide jusqu'au 31/12/2019</th>
      </tr>
      <tr *ngFor="let main of total_by_level | keyvalue;let i = index;">
        <a class="flex1 bold w-100 pointer ml-2 text-decoration-none">
          <a  data-toggle="collapse"
              (click)="collapse=!collapse"
              href="#collapseReseau-{{ i }}" aria-expanded="false"
              aria-controls="collapseReseau"
              class="unsetColor w-100">
            <i class="fa" [ngClass]="{' fa-plus': collapse, ' fa-minus': !collapse}"></i> <span class="pl-2">{{label_name[main.key]}}</span>  <span  style="float: right;"> {{totalPerCat[i]}} {{currencyCode}}</span>
            <br>
            <a class="collapse w-100" id="collapseReseau-{{ i }}">
              <a *ngFor="let sub of main.value | keyvalue" class=" ml-2 semiSmall text-black " style="display: block">
                <span class="float-left">Prix total {{label_name[sub.key]}} :</span> <span  style="float: right;">{{sub.value}} {{currencyCode}}</span>
                <br>
              </a>
            </a>
          </a>
        </a>
      </tr>
      <tr *ngIf="showAleas" class="flex1 medium-font dark-grey-text bg-grey bold">
        <th>ALEAS CHANTIERS <span  style="float: right;"> {{quotArray.quotation.total_aleas}} {{currencyCode}}</span></th>
      </tr>
      <tr *ngIf="showSupportage" class="flex1 medium-font dark-grey-text bg-grey bold">
        <th>SUPPORTAGE <span  style="float: right;"> {{quotArray.quotation.meter_supportage}} {{currencyCode}}</span></th>
      </tr>
      <tr *ngIf="showMainOeuvre" class="flex1 medium-font dark-grey-text bg-grey bold">
        <th>MAIN D'OEUVRE <span  style="float: right;"> {{quotArray.quotation.time_main_oeuvre}} {{currencyCode}}</span></th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="flex-row">
        <th class=" text-white bg-gold large-font total-sticky">
          TOTAL : <span class="float-right">{{totalTotal}}  {{currencyCode}}</span>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </table>


  </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Service :

```
  checkExistQuot(): Observable<ExistQuotModel> {
      const urlSegment = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.firstChild.url[1].path;
      if (this.urlQuot !== null ) {
      return this.httpClient.get<ExistQuotModel>(`myUrl/${urlSegment}/quotation/${this.urlQuot}?token=${this.token.token}`)
          .pipe(
              tap(data =>
                console.log('Check Exist Quote Done ', data)),
              catchError(QuotationMenuService.handleError)
            );
      } else {
        console.log('La valeur URL quot est nulle' );
      }
  }


  postQuotationDatas(): Observable<ExistQuotModel> {
    this.urlQuot = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.firstChild.url[3].path;
    const urlSegment = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.firstChild.url[1].path;
    console.log('Passage par Post Quotation')
    return this.httpClient.post<ExistQuotModel>(myUrl/${urlSegment}/quotation/${this.urlQuot}/${this.part_id}/quotationdetail?token=`,
      {
        token: this.token.token,
        part_type: this.part_type,
        longueur: this.longueur,
        quantity: this.quantity,
        hasValve: this.hasValve
      });
  }
```

Comment: can u post your template code as well ?

Comment: this can be caused by multiple subscriptions without unsubscribing afterwards. not sure in your case as i don't see the code of the service nor the template code. On HTTP requests it is not necessary to unsubscribe. 
perhaps those links might help: https://blog.fullstacktraining.com/unsubscribe-from-angular-rxjs-subscription/ and https://angular.io/guide/observables

Comment: Hey, I edited the post with both htmls and the service, thx @JonathanPauw gonna have a look

Comment: in your ngOnChanges, what is changing? you can do `ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) { console.log(changes); ` and then use an if statement to see if you need to fire off to the server because what is changing might not be relevant to calling the server

Comment: @rhavelka why im using onChanges() there is to update the view of the component with the data it just received from the server

Comment: @Zephyr the issue is that onChanges() could fire for many different reasons. You are expecting it to fire once, and only once. You likely shouldn't use onChanges() at all and should instead use property setters to trigger your changes that you need to make.